# LINQ - Left Join of 3 ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have three classes defined like this:

```
public class MaterialByOperator
{
    public int IdOperator{ get; set; }
    public int IdMaterial { get; set;}
}

public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AssignedOperator
{
     public int idOperation { get; set; }
     public int idOperator { get; set; }
}
```

`IdMaterial` in `MaterialByOperator` is a "ForeignKey" for `Material`. The relationship is `One to Many`.

`IdOperator` in `MaterialByOperator` is a "ForeignKey" for `AssignedOperator` in a `One to One` relationship.

Then I define this 3 `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Material> Materials;
public ObservableCollection<MaterialByOperator> MaterialsXOperator;
public ObservableCollection<AssignedOperator> AssignedOperators;
```

What i want is to get the operator names who does not have any materials asigned. I now do it like this:

```
var mate = MaterialsXOperator.GroupBy(x => x.idOperator); //Group materials by operatorId
//left join assignedOperators with the grouped materials
var opeasigmate = AssignedOperators.GroupJoin(mate, oper => oper.idOperator, 
                   grupo => grupo.Key, (oper, grupo) => new { oper, grupo });
var operWithoutmate = opeasigmate.Where(x => x.grupo.Count() == 0);
```

What I want to know, as my LINQ knowledge is not very wide (believe it or not, i had it forbidden in my job for years) is there any simplest way of archieving what i want? As i have told, my solution works but i'd like to see other points of view to hopefully learn by the way.

Comment: Are you performing operations against DB or against in-memory data? Your classes are missing description of Operator, there is just OperatorId, but you need it's name. What is IdOperation?

Comment: There is a simpler way using `Any`, but your is the most efficient, so I would keep it the way it is.

Comment: This is just a minimum example from a wider working code. Of course i've got Operator name, but for the sample is irrelevant, as the question is about the joining the 3 observablecollections to get Operators assigned to a Operation without material assigned. I know is a bit complex sample. The operations against memory or DB is irrelevant also, but for the sample let's assume they are in memory.

Comment: Off topic and out of curiosity, why was LINQ forbidden at your job?

Comment: Thanx @IvanStoev. I though of using Any(), but I needed the list of "Operators", not only if there were any without material.

Comment: @WicherVisser Well..because my boss didn't know anything about it. You know how bosses are ;)

Comment: Btw, memory vs DB **is** relevant, because db query optimizers can choose one and the same plan from different type of queries (introducing or removing joins) while in LINQ to Objects everything executes exactly the way you write it.

Comment: Ok @IvanStoev you are right. But would it change the way you would write the LINQ query?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I know this makes LINQ idea broken, but that's the reality.

Comment: See? I didn't know about that. Thank you @IvanStoev :)

Comment: See left outer join on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Wow,didn't knew that page. Seems very,very interesting. Bookmarked,thank you very much @jdweng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Any` is definitely simpler:

```
var operWithoutmate = AssignedOperators
    .Where(ao => !MaterialsXOperator.Any(mo => mo.IdOperator == ao.idOperator);
```

But using `join` in general is more efficient, so I would suggest you keeping it that way. The only improvement could be to replace `x.grupo.Count() == 0` with `!x.grupo.Any()`. Also the `GroupBy` in this case is redundant, so the query could be:

```
var operWithoutmate = AssignedOperators
    .GroupJoin(MaterialsXOperator, ao => ao.idOperator, mo => mo.IdOperator,
        (ao, moGroup) => new { ao, moGroup })
    .Where(r => !r.moGroup.Any())
    .Select(r => r.ao);
```

I personally find the query syntax to be easier and more readable when there are joins involved:

```
var operWithoutmate = 
    from ao in AssignedOperators
    join mo in MaterialsXOperator on ao.idOperator equals mo.IdOperator into moGroup
    where !moGroup.Any()
    select ao;
```

Comment: That's a very interesting solution. And definitely the improvement suggested is very good. If i'm not wrong, `Count()` iterates all results and `Any()`does not?

Comment: Correct. You don't need to count the coins in your pocket in order to know whether your pocket is empty :)

Comment: Thanx again..I'll wait a few minutes to see if there is another answer and if not i'll accept yours.

Comment: A pity I couldn't upvote you more. Tried both of your solutions and they work perfect, and analizing them i've learned a lot. Thank you very much Ivan.